# The percentage of journeys made by public transport is 3%/3

Tags: writing, ielts, academic-writing

Which is correct?

> The percentage of journeys made by public transport is 3%.

or

> The percentage of journeys made by public transport is 3

Comment: Neither is correct. What you are trying to say that: **Three per cent of journeys are made by/on public transport.** Or possibly: **Public transport represents 3% of journeys made.**

Comment: Thank you, @RonaldSole